# Socket Exception on ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, mysql

I am getting following exception:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A request to send or receive data
>   was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending
>   on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
>   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown how)    at
>   MySql.Data.Common.SocketStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   count)    at System.IO.BufferedStream.ReadByte()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PacketReader.ReadHeader()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PacketReader.OpenPacket()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()    at
>   DataAcessLayer.SQLData.ExecuteNonQuery(String sql, MySqlParameter[] p)
>   in e:Live ApplicationFMSGSFMSApp_CodeDataAccessLayerSQLData.cs:line 42

I am using MYSQL.dll for DB connection. What does this exception mean? Please let me know if you required any other information.

The code for which I was getting exception;

```
public static int ExecuteNonQuery(string sql, MySqlParameter[] p)
    {
        MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(strConn);
        int retval = 0;
        try
        {
            cnn.Open(); // this is line no 42 which throws error
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, cnn);
            if (p == null)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            else
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (p != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p[i]);
                }
            }
            retval = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (cnn != null)
            {
                cnn.Close();
            }
            TealErrorLog.addError(4, "SQLData.cs at Line 65; Query:" + sql, ex.ToString() + " Parameters:" + p.ToString(), MySQLCommonFunctions.toMySQLDate(DateTime.Now.ToString()));
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cnn != null)
            {
                cnn.Close();
            }
        }
        return retval;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome! put your code example that what you try for. and visit link **[How to Ask A Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Comment: Can you share you connection string? Also are you able connect to the server from workbench?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes I am able to connect mysql through workbench. Tough on quite frequent basis my MYSQL services gets stopped and I have to restart it. Connection String : <add key="MySQLConnectionString" value="Persist Security Info=False;database=fms;server=localhost; Port=3306; user id=root; pwd=password;pooling=false; " />

Comment: I think you need to dig into why the service is stopped. You can start by looking at event viewer to see if there are any unexpected errors or logs which can give you insight of reason behind service stop.

Comment: Can you see this connection string in debug mode inside that method? Notice the exception says "no address was supplied".

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/crashing.html

Comment: @heringer Yes I am able to see the string inside the method.

Comment: I had this exact error, and it was caused by my connection timing out, I raised the timeout above the default 15 seconds (i used 600 seconds) and it worked.